# how to shorten git to g by using a alias

Tags: git, bashrc, bash-alias

I am running git 2.7.2.windows.1 and I have edited my .bashrc file to have this line

```
alias g='git'
```

but when I type `g status` I get an error

```
bash: g: command not found
```

I even tried editing my global `.gitconfig` to have this line

```
[alias]
g=git
```

still getting the same error. Any way to shorten my git command to just `g` ?

Both the files above are in my `c:\users\mylogin` folder.

Comment: it seems your Windows bash is not reading your .bashrc file. Either it is in the wrong place or contains an error. You'll find that the command `alias g=git` will work fine interactively.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick `alias g='git'`, the `'`s are required.

Comment: @DavidPostill: Have you actually tried it on a Linux box (I did, using alias p=pwd; alias d=date; p; d; d '+%D' etc etc)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Fair enough. All the examples I've ever seen use `'`s. I wonder why if they are not necessary.

Comment: figured it out. I had to source my bashrc file `source ~/.bashrc` That kinda rebooted my settings and got the short forms working.